# jquery list i am getting from data attributes need to be single quoted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the list of the columns from the data attribute as:

```
var i = $(this).data('mylist');
```

works very well, so i have no control what is coming from db side, i want to wrap the each element of the list with single quotes in `jquery`, what is the possible way of doing it

i have it like this;

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

want it like this

```
'a','b','c','d','e'
```

i tried using the `toString` value but that is not giving me the results as expected

Comment: What does `$(this).data('mylist')` returns? String `a,b,c,d,e` or an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.
first convert string to array then join it back to string.

```js
let currentString = "a,b,c,d,e";


function formatString(str){
  return `'${str.split(",").join("','")}'`;
}

console.log(formatString(currentString));
```

Comment: because the first element will be missing the starting quote and last will be missing ending quote and to add them I added template literals. (A better way to format string ... don't you think)

Comment: it should be like this 

["authorid", "firstname", "lastname", "sorted", "createdon", "modifiedby"]


 ["authorid,firstname,lastname,sorted,createdon,modifiedby"]